# Can't change font or colors in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to change font and text colors in Visual Studio Professional 2015, but the options don't exist. I have my solution open/loaded, it's C#/MVC.

The problem happened after I signed into my Microsoft account in VS. My custom colors were imported from my account, but I couldn't make any changes to them. (The changes saved, but colors weren't actually updated in the editor.) I ran `devenv /resetsettings`, that led to the current problem. I then repaired VS, that didn't fix the problem. I also tried `devenv /ResetUserData`, that didn't work. I tried importing a theme from [studiostyl.es](https://studiostyl.es). The theme colors *do* show up in the editor, but I still cannot customize them as seen in the screenshot below.

**UPDATE:** I completely uninstalled VS then reinstalled it, the problem has persisted. I'm out of ideas at this point.

Why am I unable to change my color settings?

[image: settings window with nothing available]

I sometimes receive this error when opening the Fonts and Colors tab specifically. The only error in the referenced file is given below the image.

[image: fonts and colors error]

```
<entry>
    <record>396</record>
    <time>2016/01/26 19:18:52.544</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft Data Transformation Services Designer][Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]:{   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)}</description>
    <guid>{96B36E93-F71C-4160-A4EA-26AE801D2F63}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Comment: And what did you find when you examined the file it indicates?

Comment: @KenWhite I've updated the question with the error from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was ultimately unable to solve the problem. Since nothing related to Visual Studio worked (uninstalling, purging data, etc.), I had to reinstall Windows. Drastic solution, but this is my work computer and I need Visual Studio to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I was finally able to solve it by reinstalling the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501) (also known as *SSDT*), hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem when trying to switch VS2015 to use a newly installed font, and discovered that the problem appears to be related to installing and switching to the font while VS is open. The following fixed the issue for me:

1. Close VS.
2. If the font you wish to switch to is already installed, uninstall it.
3. Open VS and confirm that the font is no longer available (may be unnecessary)
4. Close VS again.
5. Reinstall the font.
6. Open VS.
7. Switch to the newly installed font.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this indeed solves the problem, feel sorry for the folks who had to reinstall windows to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you get the error message the computer is looking in a folder that is inaccessible via the computer, I tend to have this when I save word documents from the internet. Go into the \AppData\Roaming\etc... folder and copy paste the folder you need into another directory. I wouldn't remove the folder from the original place you found it just create another. Seems to have issues when dealing with the \Roaming\ file.

Hope this helps!